# Drupal 7: Adding a save button to save content to user profile page

Tags: users

I want a signed-in user to have the ability to save an image (that is being displayed in some kind of slideshow or gallery) and have it appear on that users profile page. So the image will be on the same site, maybe added by another user or the site admin and then any other user would be able to click a save button and have it added to their own profile. That image being saved (when being saved to the users profile) should have a link that returns you to the gallery from which you saved it.

How to do this?

Comment: Why not use something like a "Favorites" or flag kind of system? So instead the user can bookmark/favorite/flag the page/image that is then attached to their account?

Comment: Hi Kyle. That's exactly what I'm after. The question I have, what's the best way to do it? Is there a module I can use......or do I need to program it. I don't really have the programming experience to write it myself. Thanks, James.

Comment: I'll post my answer below, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 1):

For something really simple, you can use the [Favorites](https://drupal.org/project/favorites) module where users can add nodes to a "favorites" list. This is based off of the URL though, so a gallery of images rotating on one page wouldn't really work.

For a more robust system, you can configure a bunch of [Flags](https://drupal.org/project/flag), which can do many different things like bookmarks, favorites, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. One more question. If I had a display of bookmarked images on my user profile page, do you think it's possible to be able to link back to the same place in the  gallery from the image came from? I'm basing this off an existing site that I really like. thanks, again, James.